# Magento: Walking a collection of configurables in a module Observer.php file

Tags: magento

In my model observer class I have:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'short_description', 'description', 'price', 'image', 'status', 'manufacturer', 'url_path'), 'inner');
```

I then try to iterate:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($products->getSelect(), array('productCallback'), array('arg1' => '===='));
```

This is cribbed from the Fontis tutorial:

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/loading-large-collections

Now I want to add my function into my class:

```
private function xproductCallback($args)
{
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setData($args['row']);

  if ($product->getTypeId()=="configurable") {
    echo $args['arg1'] . "\n";
    echo $product->getSku() . ': ' . $product->getName() . "TYPE ". $product->getTypeId() ."\n";
    }
}
```

Now does it work? Don't think so:

`Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'productCallback' not found or invalid function name app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Iterator.php on line 50`

So where should I put my callback function?

Also weird is how the collection works. I only want product type configurable but when I add

`->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::CONFIGURABLE))` (or any variant thereof) it doesn't give me a collection of configurables to walk. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The callback `productCallback` would mean a global function, whereas your function is in fact an instance method. You need to provide an object too:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')
    ->walk($products->getSelect(),
           array(array($this, 'productCallback')),
           array('arg1' => '===='));
```

(The reason it's a double-nested array is because `walk()` expects a *list* of callbacks)

Also it seems your actual function name is misspelt, but that might be a typo in the question rather than in the program.

**PS**
Reading the tutorial I notice it says:

> I have used the example of a simple callback function [...] If you're using this code inside a class and want to use a class method for the callback instead of a function, you'll need to change the code

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Weirdly it picks up the function if I place it in the frontend .phtml file. But we know that is morally wrong. I eventually added an event observer to the config.xml so that I could include the method - that lets me keep my callback code in the same Observer.php code - no 'private' function, so that will be global?